# php pdo construct mysql call extremely slow on drupal 7 site using nginx and php-fpm

Tags: mysql, drupal, pdo, php

I have a drupal website that is calling the static PDO `__contruct` for a mysql connection, on a remote server at first and then changed to a local server to remove network latency for sanity checking.

On the local db call I am getting the following generated from xhprof and an extremely slow page load.

```
Function Name    | Calls | Calls% | Incl. Wall Time(ms) | IWall% | Excl. Wall Time(ms) | EWall%
PDO::__construct | 6     | 0.0%   | 120,084,724         | 91.6%  | 120,084,724         | 91.6%
```

The php version is 5.4 on debian wheezy. The website is on a nginx and php5-fpm stack. The MySQL version is 5.5.

The tables are MyISAM but were originally InnoDB and had the same issue.

Does anyone know what could be causing this delay in the connection?

Comment: Did you try both with `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`? What about a unix socket?

Comment: @Maerlyn, on MySQL localhost means unix socket, but yes connections should be tested with sockets, IP and DNS name (to check DNS resolutions issues)